# What is the difference between both proxy_read_timeout and fastcgi_read_timeout?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

... when Nginx acts as a front end to PHP-FPM?

Nginx is a proxy and PHP is served via fastcgi... so, do both apply?

Background:
Nginx reported a lot of timeouts, as the response from PHP-FPM took too long, so I have to figure out which value I have to increase.

Comment: `proxy_read_timeout` is applied when nginx proxies via `HTTP` protocol (for example, if you used nginx to proxy the request to a server such as `node.js`). `fastcgi_read_timeout` is used when nginx speaks to the other service using `FastCGI` protocol. I would suggest that you debug why PHP takes a long time to respond back instead of increasing the timeout, because you *might* be on the path of burying every evidence of a severe problem.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I had a look at why PHP needs so long - it is an IO issue, so not too easy to overcome.

Comment: i am using nginx + gunicorn. which setting would apply for me  ?